# array_add method In laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I try to use `array_add` method to add new element to array in for loop

```
public function getNotArray() {
    // looping over $service Object
    for($x = 0; $x < count($service); $x++) {
        $firstService[$x] = $service[$x]->first_date_for_service;
        while (Carbon::now() > $firstService[$x]) {
            $firstService[$x]->addMinutes($service[$x]->notification_period);
            if($firstService[$x] < Carbon::now() && $firstService[$x] > $service[$x]->serviceHistory->where('status','done')->max('created_at')) {
                $arr[] = array_add($service[$x], 'notificationDate', date($firstService[$x]));
            }
        }
    }
    return  $arr;
}
```

The above script working well, **but return `notificationDate` fixed value** when loop over `$arr`

I need to get `notificationDate` according for value that  `$firstService[$x]` carries in each loop

Any Suggestions,Thanks

Comment: So I'm assuming you want to make it variable?

Comment: no `$firstService[$x]` carries different value in each loop **i tried it in another script** but i need both `$service[$x]` and `$firstService[$x]`
So  i did this above script.

Comment: Can you please post an example input and output?

Comment: what is input and output exactly you want ?

Comment: your service variable is an object ,  for merge use collections to update that
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections

Comment: @Mohammad:when i use collection i can not loop over `$arr` in my view .

Comment: use $collection->toArray(); to converts collection to array

Comment: @Mohammad: is already in `[]` look to above code again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public function getNotArray() {
  // looping over $service Object
  for($x = 0; $x < count($service); $x++) {

     $firstService[$x] = $service[$x]->first_date_for_service;

     while (Carbon::now() > $firstService[$x]) {

       $firstService[$x]->addMinutes($service[$x]->notification_period);

       if($firstService[$x] < Carbon::now() && $firstService[$x] > $service[$x]->serviceHistory->where('status','done')->max('created_at')) {

          $service[$x] = array_add($service[$x], 'notificationDate', date($firstService[$x]));

       }
     }
   }
   return  $service;
 }
```